# In CFT, is the unique state killed by the dilation operator $D$ necessarily killed by the momentum $P_\mu$?

Tags: hilbert-space, representation-theory, conformal-field-theory, vacuum, lie-algebra

Suppose a CFT hilbert space contains a unique state $|0\rangle$ satisfying $D|0\rangle = 0$, where $D$ is the dilation generator.

By assuming $D\geq 0$, one can prove $K_\mu|0\rangle = 0$ (since $K_\mu$ is a lowering operator, if $K_\mu|0\rangle$ were nonzero it would have negative dilation eigenvalue, a contradiction).

By looking at the $[D,M_{\mu\nu}]$ and $[M_{\mu\nu},M_{\rho\sigma}]$ commutators, one can also show $M_{\mu\nu}|0\rangle = 0$ - at least in $d>2$. I'll omit the details here.

That leaves $P_\mu$, the momentum. Is it necessarily true that $P_\mu|0\rangle = 0$? That is, does assuming $D\geq 0$ with unique ground state $|0\rangle$ necessarily imply that $P_\mu|0\rangle = 0$? I've not been able to prove it, but it seems like it ought to be true.

Answer (score 3):

In a unitary theory yes, otherwise not necessarily. To show this in a unitary theory, compute the norm of $P_\mu|0\rangle$ in the standard way
$$
(P_\mu|0\rangle)^\dagger P_\mu|0\rangle=\langle 0|K_\mu P_\mu|0\rangle
$$
(no summation). Use the commutator between $K$ and $P$ and things you already know to show this norm is zero.